# Monkey Patching React Components

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I define a component like this:

```
const myComponent = class MyComponent extends React.Component {}
```

and later I would like to add a constructor to the defined component like this:

```
myComponent.constructor = function(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = { hello: 'world' }
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, does anyone know what differences in implementation are required compared to the above? Thanks!

Comment: Is this "for science" or do you have some good reason to do this?

Comment: I'd really love to hear your use case as well. Components are generally designed to be re-usable and "dumb". Overriding the constructor reaches a little deep into the component for my taste. Maybe you can deal with differences in behavior by passing props instead?

Comment: Came for the use case too, if I understood correctly what you're intending is to monkey patch classes in js and it doesn't sound right

Answer (score 4):

You can not override constructor for es6 classes. You can do it with es5 classes, so it would work (and be brittle) with babel.

For other methods you would do

```
MyComponent.prototype.methodName = function() {}
```

This is IMO a missing feature as it would allow better dependency injection.

If TC39 should stumble onto this page I would love to have Reflect.setConstructor.